# How to resize a texture for meters in ARKit

Tags: arkit, scnmaterial

I need to tile a texture across a plane with updating geometry (floor fill), and I need the texture to be scaled to fit real-world dimensions in centimeters. It is a square floor tile of 50cm, and the texture size is 1024 pixels. How do I convert pixels to meters in `ARKit`? i know that I have to use `SCNMatrix4MakeScale` on the `SCNMaterial diffuse.contentsTransform` but not sure what properties to set to get it accurate.

Answer (score 1):

What you might do is use the physical size of `SCNNode` that you are working with and determine how much squares of 50x50cm could it fit. After you get this coefficient, use it inside the `contentsTransform` to achieve needed behavior. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47364341/4108415) answer for code snippets and more hints that you might find useful.
[image]